# How to extract numbers from a string that has no spaces into a list

Tags: python, list, data-extraction, strsplit

I have an assignment for which my script should be able to receive a string for input (e.g. `"c27bdj3jddj45g"` ) and extract the numbers into a list (not just the digits, it should be able to detect full numbers).
I am not allowed to use regex at all, only simple methods like split, count and append.
Any ideas? (Using python)

Example for the output needed for the string I gave as an example:
`['27','3', '45']`

Nothing I have tried so far is worth mentioning here, I am pretty lost on which approach to take here without `re.findall`, which I cannot use.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "full numbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `for-loop` and save the `numbers`. Then, when you see no digit, append digits and reset the string.

```
s = 'g38ff11'
prv = ''
res = []
for c in s:
    if c.isdigit():
        prv += c
    else:
        if prv != '': res.append(prv)
        prv = ''
if prv != '': res.append(prv)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['38', '11']
```

You can also write a lambda to check and append:

```
s = 'g38ff11'
prv = ''
res = []
append_dgt = lambda prv, res: res.append(prv) if prv!=""  else None
for c in s:
    if c.isdigit():
        prv += c
    else:
        append_dgt(prv,  res)
        prv = ''
append_dgt(prv, res)
print(res)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! This almost works, the only issue I’m having is that if the string I choose ends with a digit and not a letter the last digit/number is not appended into the list (e.g. input f38gg11 results in ['38'] and not ['38', '11'] , any idea why?

Comment: @Rp1013, edited the answer, you can see and say, is this solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it is to use the *groupby* from itertools lib:

```py
from itertools import groupby

s = 'c27bdj3jdj45g11'                # last dight is 11
ans = []

for k, g in groupby(s, lambda x: x.isdigit()):
    if k:               #  True if x is digit
        ans.append(''.join(g))

        
ans
['27', '3', '45', '11']
```

**Second solution** - even OP has opt out the regex, but this is just for a reference. (to show how much easier to approach this type of puzzle - which should be t*he way to go)*

You could try to use regex - **re** lib like this (if there's no *restriction!)*

```py
s = 'c27bdj3jddj45g'

import re

list(re.findall(r'\d+', s))     #  matching one more digits
['27', '3', '45']

# or to get *integer*
list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', s)))
[27, 3, 45]
```

Comment: From question : *I am not allowed to use regex at all*

Comment: Wow... miss that *statement*.  But will put disclaimer for a reference...  ;-)

Comment: @Rp1013 - just post another solution.  check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
s='c27bdj3jddj45g'
lst=[]
for x in s:
    if x.isdigit():
        lst.append(x)
    else:
        lst.append('$')  # here $ is appended as a place holder so that all the numbers can come togetrher
```

Now, `lst` becomes :

```
#['$', '2', '7', '$', '$', '$', '3', '$', '$', '$', '$', '4', '5', '$']
```

`''.join(lst).split('$')` becomes:

```
['', '27', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '45', '']
```

Finally doing list comprehension to extract the numbers:

```
[x for x in ''.join(lst).split('$') if x.isdigit()]
['27', '3', '45']
```

Answer (score 0):

string='c27bdj3jddj45g'

`lst=[]`

for i in string:

```
if i.isdigit():
    lst.append(i)
else:
    lst.append('$')
print([int(i) for i in ''.join(lst).split('$') if i.isdigit()])
```